# Passing phone number to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

Im attempting to pass phone number from button on html page, the problem is each time the page loads the id of the button (may change) so cant capture from its Id ( I dont think ).

The problem lies in that it seems to pass as integer, but this misses off the 0 at the start. Is there anyway to pass via string, as I believe this would resolve the issue.

$phone_details[] is an array of details..

```
<script>
 function showNumber(id)
 {
  alert(id);
 }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type='button' value='".$phone_details[1]." ".$phone_details[2]."' onclick='showNumber(".$phone_details[0].")'>
```

Comment: you should post your complete code.

Comment: I am so confused.. you are passing a string literal into the `showNumber` function - how would it be passing it as an integer?

Comment: For example when passing 01234 - it only alerts 1234 - need full thing

Comment: @mhodges It's PHP. They're passing an element from an array to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading this with PHP, aren't you? You are missing some additional quotes:

```
<input type='button' value='".$phone_details[1]." ".$phone_details[2]."' onclick='showNumber(\"".$phone_details[0]."\")'>
```

See the added ", this will ensure that you are sending "0123" (string) instead of 0123 (number) and therefore it will keep the leading 0.

You can test very easily with simple alerts. The first one without quotes, the second with quotes:

```js
alert(06512300);
alert("06512300");
```

If that doesn't work, then you should ensure that you are printing phone_details[0] as a string. I do not think that's your issue, but if it is, check: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: BTW numbers with a leading zero are treated as octals unless they're invalid octals and then are treated as integers without leading zeros.

Comment: Yeah, but I did not want to cause confusion as the question is just about keeping the leading 0 (i.e. sending as a string in Javascript).

Comment: Still no joy. tried just to pass some numbers 012234
 but still no luck

Comment: You missed backslashing the second quote on the value: `<input type='button' class='btn-delete' value='".$Driver_details[1]." ".$Driver_details[2]."' onclick='deleteDriver(\'0222\')'>` - personally, I would backslash the double quotes to avoid conflicts within the PHP code rather than the single quotes within the HTML.

Comment: the button is within echo("") - still not working though

Comment: When I pass 1234 with out quotes it shows as if its 146

Comment: You should always send with quotes. It's string, not numbers.